# How to generate dynamic graph at runtime in amcharts..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ubuntu-14.04, amcharts

Following is the code of Multiple Value Axes:

In that we want to show the graph by using random data dynamically.
when we run this code nothing will be happened.

```
<script>
var chart;
var chartData = [];
// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 50);
    var v = [];
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);}
     for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {   
        v[j] = Math.round(Math.random() * 40 *j) + 100;
         chartData.push({
            date: newDate,
            a + j.toString():v[j]
          // a + j = stringValue - 0;
          //var a[j]:v[j],       
        });   
     }   
    }
}
// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    chart.zoomToIndexes(10, 20);
}
// create chart
AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // generate some random data first
    generateChartData();

    // SERIAL CHART    
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.marginTop = 0;
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
    chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
    chart.zoomOutButton = {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        backgroundAlpha: 0.15
    };
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "date";
    // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is inited) and call zoomChart method when it happens
    chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
    // AXES
    // category                
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
    categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
    categoryAxis.dashLength = 2;
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
    categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
    // first value axis (on the left)
    var valueAxis1 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis1.axisColor = "#FF6600";
    valueAxis1.axisThickness = 2;
    valueAxis1.gridAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis1);
    // second value axis (on the right) 
    var valueAxis2 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis2.position = "right"; // this line makes the axis to appear on the right
    valueAxis2.axisColor = "#FCD202";
    valueAxis2.gridAlpha = 0;
    valueAxis2.axisThickness = 2;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis2);
    // third value axis (on the left, detached)
    valueAxis3 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis3.offset = 50; // this line makes the axis to appear detached from plot area
    valueAxis3.gridAlpha = 0;
    valueAxis3.axisColor = "#B0DE09";
    valueAxis3.axisThickness = 2;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis3);
    var  graph = [];
    var v ;
for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) 
{   
    graph[j] = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph[j].valueAxis = valueAxis1; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
    graph[j].title = "red line";
    v = a + j.toString();
    graph[j].valueField = v;
    graph[j].bullet = "round";
    graph[j].hideBulletsCount = 30;
    chart.addGraph(graph[j]);
}
    // CURSOR
    var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
    chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
    chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
    // SCROLLBAR
    var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
    chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);
    // LEGEND
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.marginLeft = 110;
    chart.addLegend(legend);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
</script>
<body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 640px: hieght: 400px: overflow: hidden: text-align: left;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking to produce 4 graphs with random values.

If that is correct, there is a number of issues with your code:

The values for each of the graph need to be consolidated into a single data point for each category. So that we get one object per category:

```
[
  {
    date: '2015-01-01',
    value1: 100,
    value2: 200,
    value3: 300,
    value4, 400
  },
  {
    date: '2015-01-02',
    value1: 101,
    value2: 201,
    value3: 302,
    value4, 404
  },
  // etc.
]
```

The best way to achieve that is to create an item with a date part, then generate a value for each graph and add them to the same object. Only then push that object into chart data array.

```
function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 50);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
    var item = {
      date: newDate
    };
    for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
      item[j.toString()] = Math.round(Math.random() * 40 * j) + 100;;
    }
    chartData.push(item);
  }
}
```

The same with adding actual graph objects. Just need to assign `valueField` to the same key as we did with data:

```
  var v;
  for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    graph[j] = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph[j].valueAxis = valueAxis1; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
    graph[j].title = "red line";
    v = j.toString();
    graph[j].valueField = v;
    graph[j].bullet = "round";
    graph[j].hideBulletsCount = 30;
    chart.addGraph(graph[j]);
  }
```

Here's the complete working code:

```js
var chart;
var chartData = [];
// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 50);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
    var item = {
      date: newDate
    };
    for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
      item[j.toString()] = Math.round(Math.random() * 40 * j) + 100;;
    }
    chartData.push(item);
  }
}

// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    chart.zoomToIndexes(10, 20);
  }
  // create chart
AmCharts.ready(function() {
  // generate some random data first
  generateChartData();

  // SERIAL CHART    
  chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
  chart.marginTop = 0;
  chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
  chart.zoomOutButton = {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    backgroundAlpha: 0.15
  };
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.categoryField = "date";
  // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is inited) and call zoomChart method when it happens
  chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
  // AXES
  // category                
  var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
  categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
  categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
  categoryAxis.dashLength = 2;
  categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
  categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
  // first value axis (on the left)
  var valueAxis1 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  valueAxis1.axisColor = "#FF6600";
  valueAxis1.axisThickness = 2;
  valueAxis1.gridAlpha = 0;
  chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis1);
  // second value axis (on the right) 
  var valueAxis2 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  valueAxis2.position = "right"; // this line makes the axis to appear on the right
  valueAxis2.axisColor = "#FCD202";
  valueAxis2.gridAlpha = 0;
  valueAxis2.axisThickness = 2;
  chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis2);
  // third value axis (on the left, detached)
  valueAxis3 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  valueAxis3.offset = 50; // this line makes the axis to appear detached from plot area
  valueAxis3.gridAlpha = 0;
  valueAxis3.axisColor = "#B0DE09";
  valueAxis3.axisThickness = 2;
  chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis3);
  var graph = [];
  var v;
  for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    graph[j] = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph[j].valueAxis = valueAxis1; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
    graph[j].title = "red line";
    v = j.toString();
    graph[j].valueField = v;
    graph[j].bullet = "round";
    graph[j].hideBulletsCount = 30;
    chart.addGraph(graph[j]);
  }
  // CURSOR
  var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
  chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
  chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
  // SCROLLBAR
  var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
  chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);
  // LEGEND
  var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
  legend.marginLeft = 110;
  chart.addLegend(legend);

  // WRITE
  chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But still it unable to solve the exact problem. I define exact problem with new Question.

Comment: this is the link of another que.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776072/how-generate-dynamic-amcharts-when-data-is-stored-in-csv-file-how-show-popup-t