# How generate dynamic amcharts, when data is stored in CSV file? How show Popup that given extra information for that value?

Tags: javascript, csv, graph, amcharts

I have a number of groups, each group has `n` number of properties. Each property has different values on each date. I have generated a graph for a selected group with `date` on x-axis and `values` on y-axis. The value of the selected group is stored in attached CSV file. I have to enerate amCharts for this CSV file.

Extra Information: value related situation, history etc.

```js
var chart;
var chartData = [];
var chartCursor;

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.pathToImages = "amcharts/images/";
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "date";
    chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

    // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is rendered) and call zoomChart method when it happens
    chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
    categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
    categoryAxis.dashLength = 2;
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
    categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
    categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";

    // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    //valueAxis.position="right";
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.2;
    valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
    showLastLabel = true;
    valueAxis.title = "Cloud Services";
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    //label
    //var allLabels = new AmCharts.allLabels();
    //allLabels.text="lable-1";
    //allLabels.bold=true;
    //allLabels.y="aws";
    //chart.addallLabels(allLabels);


    // GRAPH
    //  var  graph = [];
    // var  visits;

    //for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) 
    //{   

    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "red line";
    //visits= 
    graph.valueField = "visits";
    graph.bullet = "round";
    graph.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph.lineThickness = 2;
    graph.lineColor = "#b5030d";
    graph.negativeLineColor = "#0352b5";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>value: [[value]]</span></b>";
    graph.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
    chart.addGraph(graph);
    //}
    // GRAPH1
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph1.title = "red line";
    graph1.valueField = "visits1";
    graph1.bullet = "round";
    graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph1.lineThickness = 2;
    graph1.lineColor = "#b5030d";
    graph1.negativeLineColor = "#0352b5";
    graph1.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>value: [[value1]]</span></b>";
    graph1.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
    chart.addGraph(graph1);

    // GRAPH2
    var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph2.title = "red line";
    graph2.valueField = "visits2";
    graph2.bullet = "round";
    graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph2.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph2.lineThickness = 2;
    graph2.lineColor = "#b5030d";
    graph2.negativeLineColor = "#0352b5";
    graph2.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>value: [[value2]]</span></b>";
    graph2.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
    chart.addGraph(graph2);

    // GRAPH3
    var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph3.title = "red line";
    graph3.valueField = "visits3";
    graph3.bullet = "round";
    graph3.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph3.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph3.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph3.lineThickness = 2;
    graph3.lineColor = "#b5030d";
    graph3.negativeLineColor = "#0352b5";
    graph3.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>value: [[value3]]</span></b>";
    graph3.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
    chart.addGraph(graph3);

    // GRAPH4
    var graph4 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph4.title = "red line";
    graph4.valueField = "visits4";
    graph4.bullet = "round";
    graph4.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph4.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph4.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph4.lineThickness = 2;
    graph4.lineColor = "#b5030d";
    graph4.negativeLineColor = "#0352b5";
    graph4.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>value: [[value4]]</span></b>";
    graph4.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
    chart.addGraph(graph4);

    // CURSOR
    chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
    chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
    chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

    // SCROLLBAR
    var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
    chartScrollbar.graph = graph;
    chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 50;
    chartScrollbar.color = "#FFFFFF";
    chartScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
    chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");

    loadCSV("Na.csv");
});

function loadCSV(file) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    // load
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.send();
    parseCSV(request.responseText);
}

function parseCSV(data) {
    //replace UNIX new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    //replace MAC new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
    //split into rows
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    /* function parseCSV(data) {
                    //replace UNIX new lines
                    data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
                    //replace MAC new lines
                    data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
                    //split into rows
                    var rows = data.split("\n");
            var value;*/

    // loop through all rows

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // this line helps to skip empty rows
        if (rows[i]) {

            // our columns are separated by comma
            var column = rows[i].split(",");

            // column is array now
            // first item is date
            var date = column[0];

            // second item is value of the second column
            //  value[i] = column;

            var value = column[1];
            var value1 = column[2];
            var value2 = column[3];
            var value3 = column[4];
            var value4 = column[5];

            // create object which contains all these items:
            var dataObject = {
                date: date,
                visits: value,
                visits1: value1,
                visits2: value2,
                visits3: value3,
                visits4: value4

            };
            // add object to chartData array
            chartData.push(dataObject);
        }
    }
    chart.validateData();
}

// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 50, chartData.length - 1);
}

// changes cursor mode from pan to select
function setPanSelect() {
    if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked) {
        chartCursor.pan = false;
        chartCursor.zoomable = true;
    } else {
        chartCursor.pan = true;
    }
    chart.validateNow();
}
```

CSV file: Na.csv

```
2015-05-13,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,79,84,89,94,99,104,109,114,119,124,129,134,139,144,149,154,159,164,169,174,179,184,189,194,199,204,209,214,219,224,229,234,239,244,249,254,259,264,269,274,279,284,289,294,299,304,309,314,319,324,329,334,339,344,349,354,359,364,369,374,379,384,389,394,399,404,409,414,419,424,429,434,439,444,449,454,459,464,469,474,479,484,489,494,499,504,509,514,519,524,529,534,539
2015-05-16,3,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,79,84,89,94,99,104,109,114,119,124,129,134,139,144,149,154,159,164,169,174,179,184,189,194,199,204,209,214,219,224,229,234,239,244,249,254,259,264,269,274,279,284,289,294,299,304,309,314,319,324,329,334,339,344,349,354,359,364,369,374,379,384,389,394,399,404,409,414,419,424,429,434,439,444,449,454,459,464,469,474,479,484,489,494,499,504,509,514,519,524,529,534,539
2015-05-18,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,79,84,89,94,99,104,109,114,119,124,129,134,139,144,149,154,159,164,169,174,179,184,189,194,199,204,209,214,219,224,229,234,239,244,249,254,259,264,269,274,279,284,289,294,299,304,309,314,319,324,329,334,339,344,349,354,359,364,369,374,379,384,389,394,399,404,409,414,419,424,429,434,439,444,449,454,459,464,469,474,479,484,489,494,499,504,509,514,519,524,529,534,539
2015-05-19,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,75,84,89,94,99,104,109,114,119,124,129,134,139,144,149,154,159,164,169,174,179,184,189,194,199,204,209,214,219,224,229,234,239,244,249,254,259,260,269,274,279,284,289,294,299,304,309,314,319,324,329,334,339,344,349,354,359,364,369,374,379,384,389,394,399,404,409,414,419,424,429,434,439,444,449,454,459,464,469,474,479,484,489,494,499,504,509,514,519,524,529,534,539
2015-05-26,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,75,84,89,94,99,104,109,114,119,124,129,134,139,144,149,154,159,164,169,174,179,184,189,194,199,204,209,214,219,224,229,234,239,244,249,254,259,260,269,274,279,284,289,294,299,304,309,314,319,324,329,334,339,344,349,354,359,364,369,374,379,384,389,394,399,404,409,414,419,424,429,434,439,444,449,454,459,464,469,474,479,484,489,494,499,504,509,514,519,524,529,534,539
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Do you want to dynamically add a graph line for each column in a CSV file? If not, what is wrong with the code that you can't solve?

Comment: yes.. i want to dynamically add a graph line for each column in a csv file

Comment: yes.. i want to dynamically add a graph line for each column from csv file..